# Turn off Animation on Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a map that has a search box.  A user types an address, and presses enter.  The map then zooms out, pans to wherever the target is, then zooms in again.  I understand from documentation that this is default behavior and that it's commonly referred to as "Fly To".

The question is... How do you disable this? I don't need fancy animation, I just want it to quickly draw a new map at the Lat/Long chosen and set the zoom level I specify.

Can this be done?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I assume you're using Mapbox-GL-Geocoder.

Just use [`setFlyTo`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/master/API.md#setflyto):

```
geocoder.setFlyTo(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
map.flyTo({animate:false})
```